# Importing strings from web !! Javascript code

Tags: javascript, excel, export-to-csv

I would like to import the accounts name after @ to excel spreadsheet. For example, for the first person's account iD is martinwaller10. Second person's account ID is IanKingSky.

I want martinwaller10, IanKingSky to show up in same column of excel spreadsheet.

Comment: Your question barely makes sense. You want usernames form where?
Have you tried anything?

Comment: [Okay](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  What have you done so far?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This is not a free code-writing service, but we can help you with code you are trying to develop. Please read the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for how to split it after you import that data -> https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/1786-excel-split-text-by-space.html